# How can I set a variable in JavaScript using attributes other than tag, class or ID name?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So my question is quite simple, see the code below.
I would like to save the two spans in two different variables based on their value in the "data-language" attribute. Any idea how could I do this?

```html
<div class="language-select">
          <span class="language-item" data-language="hu">HU </span>
          <span>/ </span>
          <span class="language-item" data-language="en"> EN</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: By using an attribute selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Better have an array of languages: `const languages = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-language]")].map(ele => ele.dataset.language)`

Comment: For the spans: `const languageSpans = document.querySelectorAll("[data-language]")`

Comment: Lookup: `const languageSpansByLanguage = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-language]")].reduce((acc,ele) => (acc[ele.dataset.language] = ele,acc),{}); console.log(languageSpansByLanguage["hu"])`

Answer (score -1):

You can just use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```js
const span1 = document.querySelector('[data-language="hu"]');
const span2 = document.querySelector('[data-language="en"]');

console.log(span1, span2);
```

```html
<div class="language-select">
  <span class="language-item" data-language="hu">HU </span>
  <span>/ </span>
  <span class="language-item" data-language="en"> EN</span>
</div>
```